# how can i automate copying over files by giving a condition using python?

Tags: python, pandas, shutil

Im new to python, i have a script-

```
import glob
    import os
    import shutil
    import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.read_fwf(r'factadwords.Rout', header=None)
    end_str = '#--- END ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    #cols_to_check = ["0"]
    
    src = r'C:/Users/jj/Desktop/autotranscribe'
    dest = r'C:/Users/jj/Desktop/Bulk_Wav'
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        #for col in cols_to_check:
            if not df[0].str.contains(end_str).any():
                #def copy(src, dest):
                    for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(src,'*.Rout'), recursive=True):
                        new_path = os.path.join(dest, os.path.basename(file_path))
                        shutil.copy(file_path, new_path)
```

My sample file factadwords.Rout contains -

```
> #--- END ---------------------------------------0-----------------------------------------------------------
```

So as you can see I have put 0 in there, which means the file should copy over to the destination folder since the file doesn't contain the exact end_str

The script runs successfully for one file, however, not all the files are copied over to the destination folder. Only one file factadwords.Rout get copied over even though other rout files in the folder dont have the valid end_str. why does this happen? how do i make it recursive to copy all files in the folder without a valid end_str over to the dest folder so the task is automated without me having to manually update df each time

```
print(file_path) Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view': C:/Users/jj/Desktop/autotranscribe\factadwords.Rout
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you printed your dataframe at all?  The first step in ANY debugging effort is to print all of your intermediate values to see what you are missing.

In this case, you seem to think your dataframe will have one long column.  That's not true.  Because you have blanks in there, your dataframe has three columns:

```
      0    1                                                  2
0  #---  END  ---------------------------------------0------...
```

So when you refer to `df[0]`, that field does NOT have a '0' in it.

Comment: it does have a '0' in it

Comment: Have you done `print(file_path)` in the inner loop to see what files it thinks it is seeing?

Comment: I have been banned from asking questions because of this post. Can you please work with my to make my question more acceptable? I want to fix this

Comment: You would not have been banned because of this question.  But when you add more info, you should edit the question, and not use comments.  Comments can't be formatted.